# Unable to get starttime and endtime from google calendar event feed

Tags: python, xml-parsing, google-api, google-calendar-api

This is a code issue. The below is the code i use to retrieve all calendar events from google calendar in a particular date range. I am able to parse who part of the event but not when part of the event.

```
def retrieve_date_range_query(self,start_date='2013-09-28', end_date='2013-10-01'):
        print 'Date range query for events on Primary Calendar: %s to %s' % (start_date, end_date,)
        query = gdata.calendar.service.CalendarEventQuery('default', 'private', 'full')
        query.start_min = start_date
        query.start_max = end_date
        feed = self.cal_srv.CalendarQuery(query)
        print feed
        for i, an_event in enumerate(feed.entry):
            print '\t%s. %s' % (i, an_event.title.text,)
# 
            for p, a_participant in enumerate(an_event.who):
                    print '\t\t%s. %s' % (p, a_participant.email,)
# Method 1 to retrieve starttime and endtime of the event - but it fails
            for p, a_participant in enumerate(an_event.when):
                    print '\t\t%s. %s' % (p, a_participant.startTime,)
                    print '\t\t%s. %s' % (p, a_participant.endTime,)
# Method 2 to retrieve starttime and endtime of the event - this too fails
#  Value for a_when here is When: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?> <ns0:when xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005" endTime="2013-09-30T09:00:00.000+05:30" startTime="2013-09-30T08:00:00.000+05:30" />
            for a_when in an_event.when:
                print '\t\tStart time: %s' % (a_when.startTime,)
                print '\t\tEnd time:   %s' % (a_when.endTime,)
```

I mostly reflect the community code above from this [link](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v1/developers_guide_python#RetrievingDateRange). And thoroughly analysed the xml data of the when and who objects. I surprise to see that i am able to parse who object and not when object. Am i missing anything with the code. Is there any other information i can provide to make it better to understand. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the prob.

The variables have to be used like this

```
for a_when in an_event.when:
   print '\t\tStart time: %s' % (a_when.start_time,)
   print '\t\tEnd time:   %s' % (a_when.end_time,)
```

I am not very sure why we use start_time. But that's how it has to be used. Thanks